# Matlab dynamic legend / legend "hold on" like behavior

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Just want to add more data do a legend without erasing it. Like a legend "hold on"

**Sample**:

`plotData` = array of plot data, like plotData(i) = plot(...

`N` = size of plotData.

**Code**:

```
for i = 1:N
   str =  sprintf('My plot y %d', i);
   %legendData(:,i) = [plotData; str]; %#ok<SAGROW>
   %[~,~,~,current_entries] = legend;
   %legend([current_entries [plotData; str]]); no sucess here

   % This command will erase the previous one. 
   legend(plotData,str);
end

legend([plotX1,plotX2],'x 1','x 2');
```

I think I can store the legend info from the loop and add it some way to the final line, something like:

```
legend(DATAFROMLOOP?? [plotX1,plotX2],'x 1','x 2');
```

This is a possible solution, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set the [`DisplayName`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/primitiveline-properties.html#property_displayname) property of your plot objects and then call `legend` once when you are done plotting everything. `legend` will automatically retrieve the strings from the `DisplayName` property to populate the legend.

```
hplot1 = plot(rand(10,1), 'DisplayName', 'plot1');
hplot2 = plot(rand(10,1), 'DisplayName', 'plot2');

legend([hplot1, hplot2]);
```

[image]

You can easily incorporate this into a loop:

```
% Create 10 plots within a loop
N = 10;

% Pre-allocate graphics objects
hplots = gobject(N, 1);

for k = 1:N
    hplot(k) = plot(rand(10, 1), 'DisplayName', sprintf('My plot y %d', k));
end

legend(hplot);
```

[image]